# Given a printers.conf file, is it possible to generate the associated .ppd files programmatically?

Tags: printing

I've looked at ppdc but there doesn't seem to be a way to restrict it to just the model I want.

`cups.Connection().getPPD()` in `pycups` looked promising but it just gets an existing ppd file.

I don't really want to generate all 17MB of files just to find the one I want...

Comment: can you tell us a little more

Comment: Sorry, that did lack a little context. On Ubuntu you can go to system Settings -> Printers and Add Printer. Once you've chosen the model, etc, this generates a `printers.conf` under `/etc/cups/` and a matching printer description ppd file under `/etc/cups/ppd/`. I'd like to write a script that would let me take an existing `printers.conf` file and generate the matching ppd file on another machine. I can copy the config text but not the ppd text because of arcane security rules...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally figured it out:

1. Get printer name from printers.conf
2. Call `lpinfo` to get the ppd info
3. Call `cups-driverd cat` to get the ppd contents

Comment: great; from here https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/where-are-ppd-files-stored-gentoo-ubuntu-337393/ it is said that installed ppds are in /etc/cups/ppd. The database is in /usr/share/ppd. That seems so on ubuntu; `locate ppd` yields all